# Evaluate the following contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int_{C}\left(\exp\left(z\right)-\dfrac{2}{z^3}\right)dz$$ where C is any contour from $i$ to $-i$ which does not pass through $0$

I understand that contour integration can be evaluated as the sum of path integrals however I'm not sure what the paths would be so that they don't pass through zero.

Comment: You have a single path here. The fundamental theorem of calculus makes it easy.

Comment: @DanielFischer: shouldn't we also exploit the fact that the residue at $z=0$ is zero? The path may enclose the origin without passing through it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The FTC exploits that in a sense. The integrand is a derivative [which is equivalent to the residue being $0$], so the integral doesn't depend on the chosen path.